# Does the stack automatically get popped when leaving a function in x86 NASM assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm

For instance lets enter into a function...

```
push ebp ;Saving ebp
mov ebp, esp ;Saving esp into ebp
sub esp, 4 ;Saving four bytes onto the stack
```

And exit out of function...

```
mov esp, ebp ;Restoring the saved value of esp
pop ebp ;Restoring the value of ebp from the stack
```

(Yes I know I can use enter and leave, but I like it better this way.)

My question is when esp is restored, does the four byte variable on the stack get popped or somehow magically disappears? I couldn't see how pop  ebp wouldn't just pop the four bytes reserved (and most likely used) from the stack. To my eye if you pushed anything onto the stack during the function it would still be there when the pop ebp happens, and thus pop ebp would yield not the saved ebp, but what was on the top of the stack. Does changing the esp register just lop off the top of the stack when it's value is restored?

Comment: For the sake of being precise, the code examples you're showing concern themselves with setting up and tearing down a stack frame; they have nothing to do with entering and leaving a function. (You would typically use the `call` and `ret` instructions for that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"To my eye if you pushed anything onto the stack during the function it would still be there when the pop ebp happens[…]*"

No, because immediately before the `pop ebp` instruction, you have this:

> ```
> mov esp, ebp ;Restoring the saved value of esp
> ```

Remember that `esp` is essentially the address of the "top" of the stack. Pushing onto and popping from the stack changes this register. So if you change this register, you're changing the location where the next `push` or `pop` will happen.

So the above instruction, `mov esp, ebp` essentially resets the stack pointer to the location it had immediately after the initial `push ebp`. (That location was saved to the `ebp` register right through the `mov ebp, esp` instruction.)

That's why `pop ebp` will pop the right thing.

This does however assume that your function did not change the `ebp` register.

**Update:**

I am assuming a certain calling convention here, but let's make an example. Let's say we have a function that takes one 32-bit argument, which gets passed to the function via the call stack.

In order to call our function, we do this:

```
push eax      ; push argument on stack
call fn       ; call our function; this pushes `eip` onto the stack
```

The first thing `fn` does is to set up its own stack frame (and making sure that the previous one can be restored at the end):

```
push ebp      ; so we can later restore the previous stack frame
mov ebp, esp  ; initialize our own function's stack frame
sub esp, 8    ; make room for 8 bytes (for local variables)
```

The `sub esp, 8` is like pushing 8 bytes onto the stack, only that nothing will be written to the memory locations; so we essentially end up with 8 uninitialized bytes; this is the the memory area our function can use for local variables. It can refer to these local variables via e.g. `[ebp-4]` or `[ebp-8]`, and it can refer to its 32-bit argument via `[ebp+8]` (skipping over the pushed `ebp` and `eip`).

During your function, the stack might then look like this:

```
+------------+                         | "push" decreases "esp"
|  <arg>     |                         |
+------------+  <-- ebp+8              |
| <prev eip> |                         v
+------------+  <-- ebp+4
| <prev ebp> |
+------------+  <-- ebp
|  <locals>  |
+------------+  <-- ebp-4
|  <locals>  |                         ^
+------------+  <-- ebp-8              |
|  ...       |                         |
+------------+  <-- esp                | "pop" increases "esp"
```

At the end of the function, this will happen:

```
mov esp, ebp  ; "pop" over local variables and everything else that was pushed
pop ebp       ; restore previous stack frame
```

And finally:

```
ret           ; essentially this does a "pop eip" so program execution gets
              ; transferred back to instruction after the "call fn"
```

(PS: The calling code would have to pop the arguments passed to the function, e.g. by doing a `add esp, 4` right after the `call fn`.)

I haven't done assembly language in a long time so this is all from memory. I might be off on some of the fine points, but I hope you get the general picture.

Comment: Yes, but my question is even though esp is pointing to where it was, would there be the four bytes we used (we reserved it but did not use it, but hypothetically say we used it and loaded a value into it) still on the top of the stack (-4 from the esp)? Or would everything negative of esp just disappear. I say this because what if you wanted to push a value onto the stack post-function, would it be at -8 from esp, the previous value (at -4 from esp) still being there? Or by the resetting of esp would it remove the variable at [esp-4]?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean, _"we reserved it but did not use it?"_ What four bytes? Where did we reserve it? Use it for what purpose?

Comment: Btw. remember that on Intel CPUs the stack grows "downwards" in memory. Previously pushed values are located at addresses greather than `esp` (`esp+…`). And local variables are usually referred to via `ebp`, not via `esp` (since `esp` changes with each push/pop, while `ebp` remains stable, so local variables have "fixed" relative addresses when addressed via `ebp`).

Comment: 'mov esp, ebp  ; "pop" over local variables and everything else that was pushed'  <--- that is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, even though the answer might elaborate on the subject a little too much.

Comment: Elaboration is welcome! So every time you set esp, it pops off what is on the top of the stack?

Comment: @Sam: `add esp, …` is like one or several `pop`s, with the difference that it doesn't change any other registers or memory locations other than `esp` itself, i.e. like popping values off the stack into nirvana. `sub esp, …` is like `push`-ing, but the stack memory is not being written to, so you end up with uninitialized data on "top" of the stack. `mov esp, X` can be either such a "push" or a "pop", depending on whether `X` is greater than or less than `esp`.

Answer (score 4):

The stack has no concept of allocated vs non allocated space per sé.
This all boils down to: **conventions**.

Since the stack is a shared resource between you (the current routine), the OS and all the libraries loaded, there must be some *"social"* rules for keeping thing to get out of control.
These rules are:

1. You do not talk about the stack rules.
2. Everyone can decrement the stack pointer **whenever** they want, how much they want without asking nobody.
3. If you decrement the stack pointer by *X* then you have at the end of the day have it incremented back (in one or more steps) by exactly *X*, no more no less.

So if this is our stack state

```
     Stack decrements in this direction ==>
     ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___  
... |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___| ...
                  ^
                  |
 Stack pointer ---+
```

By the second rule we know that every thing to the right of the stack pointer
is **unsafe** as in the OS interrupt us<sup>1</sup> or we call a subroutine those memory locations will get overwritten.
We may say that what is on the left of the SP is *allocated* and what is on the right is *unallocated*.

```
     Stack decrements in this direction ==>
                    .
     Allocated      :  Unallocated
                    :
                    :
     ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___  
... |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___| ...
                  ^
                  |
 Stack pointer ---+
```

If we want to allocate some space we can again appeal to the second rule and just decrement the stack pointer.
If we happen to have the value we want to write on the new allocated space we can optimize the thing and use a `push`.

This is what happening with the code you gave

```
push ebp ;Saving ebp
mov ebp, esp ;Saving esp into ebp
sub esp, 4 ;Saving four bytes onto the stack
```

which give the stack state

```
     Stack decrements in this direction ==>
                            .
             Allocated      :  Unallocated
                            :
   4 bytes reserved --+     :
     ___ ___ ___ ___ _V_ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___  
... |___|___|___|EBP|___|___|___|___|___|___|___| ...
                  ^       ^
   Frame pointer -+       |
         Stack pointer ---+
```

Now you surely got it: *We reserve/free memory on the stack by **moving** the stack pointer*.

It doesn't matter how we move it: a `push`, a `sub`, an `and`, an `add` or a `pop` are all example of manipulation of the stack pointer that reserve/free memory on the stack.
You are free to use the one you like or best fit your needs, **you can't however lose track of what you have allocated** by the third rule.
This is why you end up with

```
mov esp, ebp ;Restoring the saved value of esp
pop ebp ;Restoring the value of ebp from the stack
```

Which simply restore the stack pointer to the *EBP* location. This could have been an `add esp, 04h` but something things get complicated and the first version is always safe.

We can use an `add` because we don't care anymore of the values stored below (on the right) of the stack pointer, so instead of doing a series of `pop` into an unused register we simply put the stack pointer back where it was, thereby freeing memory.
If we were interested in getting back the value from the stack we would use `pop` as it is the case with the *EBP* register that we must restore.

The key to understand prolog and epilog of functions is thinking not of what happend during a call but what happend during a call inside another call. If you can return from both, you fully got it.

---

<sup>1<sub>This is no longer an issue in privileged context switch as the OS has its own private privileged stack, but get along with me for the sake of clarity.</sub></sup>

Comment: Brilliant answer! some really good, easy-to-understand explanations. :-) Makes me wish I could've written an answer like that!